# How to keep fps rate constant in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have 3 question.

1. How to keep fps rate constant(almost) in cocos2d.When lots of CCSprite created and removed within a small interval like (5-8) per second is it possible to keep frame rate lmost constant??
2. Is `[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES]` is enough or I should also use

   ```
     CCTexture2D *texture = [sprite texture]; [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture: texture];
   ```
3. The following Part of code is responsible for my frame drop.How to accomplish same task in better way?

   ```
   id fadeout = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.4f];

   id call = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self   
   selector:@selector(RemoveSmashedSprite:)];

   CCSequence* sequence= [CCSequence
   actions:fadeout, call, nil];

   [smash runAction:sequence];
   ```

   ... and...

   ```
   > -(void)RemoveSmashedSprite:(id)sender
   {


       CCSprite *sp = (CCSprite *)sender;



       [self removeChild:sp cleanup:YES];  

   }
   ```

This is called 5-8 times per second. So the frame rate goes down. Can any one help me?

Comment: At last i found the problem.The problem was-  CCSprite *sp=(CCSprite*)sender;[self removeChild:sp cleanup:YES] did not remove the sender sprite smash.As a result as the game progress the more and more smash sprite are added but not removed and the memory requirement becomes greater so  the frame rate goes down.As i have used CCFadeOut in the sequence i could not understand that smash sprite is not removed,just only fade out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't remove textures if you're going to reuse them in the short term. It would only benefit memory while having a great drawback in performance.

To maintain a constant frame rate you could try reusing the sprites instead of creating and removing them. Instead of calling removeChild you could set visible = NO and add it to an array of unused sprites. Then when you need a new of these sprites you check if there is any in that unused array and only create a new one if it's empty. This way you would minimize the amount of sprites created and destroyed.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.But i noticed that if i just create and remove sprite 5-8 time per second it does not drops frame down.But if I use [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.4f]; that causes the frame rate down.So why this happen and how to mitigate it??

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
id call = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(RemoveSmashedSprite:)];
```

Into this:

```
id call = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(RemoveSmashedSprite:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove action as your last action, instead of CCCallFunc.

`id action = [CCActionRemove action];`

This action will remove the node running this action from its parent